# D3 - How to alter examples

Tags: php, graph, d3.js

I know this question is very vauge, but I am completely new to D3 and the language it uses, 0% knoweledge.

I found this example on the D3 git website:

http://dataaddict.fr/prenoms/

and I was wondering how it is possible for myself to implement this? where would I get the template code for it.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: It may be better for you to start with one of the tutorials.

Comment: what kind of tutorial woul you recommend for a line graph?

Comment: For example [this one](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/04/01/tutorial-line-chart-in-d3/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, so not really sure if you are asking for example code, what environment you need, etc.  the following list provides examples and other information about using D3 to create similar objects:

***1)*** [D3 generator dot com](http://d3-generator.com/)
***2)*** [another git example for chart](https://github.com/jgoodall/d3.chart.template)
***3)*** [horizon chart](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_horizon/)
***4)*** [re-usable charts at nvds dot org](http://nvd3.org/)

et. al.